# is there a way to clear uipickerview selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults, uipopover

I have a perfectly working uipickerview in a uipopover with a done and cancel button. I am able to save the last selected row and display it as default when the user opens the uipickerview more than once. The problem is that, when the user logs out and logs in, I want the uipickerview to start afresh ie., when I open uipickerview and click done button (without selecting any row), I want it to go with the default row ie. row0 but it is showing up the last selected row before logout!! How can I solve this?? Help much appreciated.

```
NSString *selectedType = @"ALL";
int rowselected = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    rowselected = 0;
    _typearray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ALL", @"COACH", @"GROUP", @"PRIVATE", nil];
    NSInteger lastrow =[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"gueststyperow"] integerValue];

    if(lastrow!=0)
        [self.picktype selectRow:lastrow inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    else
        [self.picktype selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}
```

//DONE BUTTON PRESSED:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",_delegate);
    NSNumber *temprow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rowselected];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:temprow forKey:@"gueststyperow"];
    [_delegate sendtype:selectedType];
}
```

//PICKERVIEW SELECTION

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
        inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        rowselected = row;
        selectedType = [_typearray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: did you try setting the pickerview to nil in the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: thanks @CaptJak ..can you be more specific on how to accomplish this in code?

Comment: What CaptKack said. Release, set to nil, and then create a new picker view.

Comment: how can i release? i am doing ARC project.. @rocky

Comment: Oh you never mentioned that so nevermind. Just set to nil then.

Comment: but how to set it to nil? I am sorry.. I am a total noob :( @rocky

Comment: @KedariTheja see my answer & let me know if that works out.

Comment: CaptJak's answer is preferred, but if you wanted to set it to nil, in Swift it would be pickerView = nil - not sure what the Obj-C equivalent is. His answer is preferred because setting it to nil and instantiating it again can cause you to lose reference to the original pickerView because when you instantiate, you're creating a new instance of the pickerView. While this isn't normally a problem, and there are ways of working around it, it's more likely to cause bugs than resetting the components of the pickerView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this above `[super viewDidLoad]`:

```
[picker reloadAllComponents];
[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

That should set your pickerview to row the 0 index every time the view is loaded.

Comment: yes its working @CaptJak..thank you...i placed it after the [super viewdidload] and it worked like a charm